# V(さ)せる when it doesn't indicate permission/compulsion

Tags: grammar

> - さくら は あたたかく なって きた ことを **しらせる ように** さきます
> - あき の おわり から はな を **さかせ** はじめ......

The above sentences use the V(さ)せる forms - though they do not indicate permission/compulsion.
Could someone help understand this form please?

Comment: http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E8%8A%B1%E3%82%92%E5%92%B2%E3%81%8B%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They actually *do* indicate compulsion:

- 知{し}らせる: Literally, "to make known", or in other words; "to inform/notify".

  > 桜は暖かくなってきたことを知らせるように咲きます。

  "The cherry blossoms bloom as if to inform [their viewers] that it has become warmer (or more freely: that warmer days have arrived)."
- 咲{さ}かせる: "to make bloom"

  > 秋の終わりから花を咲かせはじめ......

  "To make/force/let flowers start blooming from the end of autumn..."

Comment: Read further - and I find a usage in the 'causation' form.
To be the direct cause of an emotion.

Comment: @IUnknown I'm not sure what you mean... what should I "read further"?

Comment: @Will I think iUnknown means that he read (過去形) further in whatever source all of these questions are coming from and saw this further meaning. Many of iUnknown's questions feel like he doesn't put much time into trying to figure them out on his own...